# When I execute :sh in a terminal vim it exits macvim

Tags: shell, macvim

I want to execute :sh to do some quick things while in a macvim session within the terminal.  When I am in the GUI application(not in terminal) this works perfectly.  However, when I run it within the terminal it quits macvim, and executes the command inside the regular terminal.

How can I prevent this, and have it perform like the GUI version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell is running as a child of `vim`. Just exit the shell, and you should return to `vim` session.

Comment: Thanks, you just boosted my productivity by orders of magnitude